# Retrieve C# .NET image from C++ unmanaged application

Tags: c#, c++, .net, unmanaged, openframeworks

I'm using openFrameworks to render a video stream. OpenFrameworks uses the [`ofImage`](http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/graphics/ofImage.html) class, which stores the images as a vector of `ofPixel` (which stores an `unsigned char` vector).

I am using a C# .NET dll to retrieve each frame. This library uses [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) to return the retrieved frames. So far I know C# .NET works under the [Common Language Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8bs2ecf4.aspx).

My question is, what .NET tools or functionalities can I use in order to comunicate native C++ code and managed C#?

Comment: I'm trying to edit this question to get it to be acceptable, at the moment of asking it I knew nothing about C# or .NET. I'm finding it hard to improve the quality of the question. Should I delete it as the whole question shows poor research?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to retrieve the image I used [this tutorial](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Consuming-C-Library-in-937458e5). It thoroughly explains how to consume a C# managed library from unmanaged code.

The process I followed is documented [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/051d592a-76a8-4010-bfbe-e7cc9e4f8464/call-c-managed-dll-from-native-c-for-noobs#46097081-4cea-4658-ab56-6a2c6937aa97).

Here's an overview

- create a C++/CLI project (CLR Class Library in Visual Studio's New
  Project dialog)
- add a reference to the C# dll create native classes
  and/or functions that expose the necessary C# dll functionality to
  the native world;
- export them using the usual means (__declspec(dllexport) or .def file)
- add the .lib produced by the C++/CLI project as linker input in your native project(s)

About the image information, it can be referred to as a byte array. It has to be pinned in the managed code using a GCHandle. Here is some code to illustrate this concept (Disclaimer, this answer was provided by another author in the [original msdn forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/051d592a-76a8-4010-bfbe-e7cc9e4f8464/call-c-managed-dll-from-native-c-for-noobs#46097081-4cea-4658-ab56-6a2c6937aa97)):

```
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

std::unordered_map<void *, void *> dataHandles;

void *getData() {
    array<Byte>^ arr = gcnew array<Byte>(2);
    arr[0] = 'C';
    arr[1] = '#';

    GCHandle handle = GCHandle::Alloc(arr, GCHandleType::Pinned);
    void *data = (void *)handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    dataHandles.insert(std::make_pair(data, (void *)GCHandle::ToIntPtr(handle)));
    return data;
}

void releaseData(void *data) {
    auto i = dataHandles.find(data);

    if (i != dataHandles.end())
        GCHandle::FromIntPtr((IntPtr)i->second).Free();
}

#pragma unmanaged

void native() {
    char *data = (char *)getData();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        printf("%c ", data[i]);

    releaseData(data);
}

#pragma managed

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args) {
    native();
    return 0;
}
```

More about specific `Bitmap` to `unsigned char *` conversion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18407349/2628257)