# System::Drawing::Bitmap to unsigned char *

Tags: c#, c++, .net, bitmap, openframeworks

I have a C# .NET library that grabs frames from a camera. I need to send those frames to a native application that takes images from an `unsigned char*`.

I initially take the frames as `System::Drawing::Bitmap`.

So far I can retrieve a `byte[]` from the `Bitmap`. My test is done with an image of resolution 400*234, I should be getting 400*234*3 bytes to get to the 24bpp a RGB image requires.

However, I'm getting a `byte[]` of size 11948.

This is how I convert from `Bitmap` to `byte[]`:

```
private static byte[] ImageToByte(Bitmap img)
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
}
```

What is the proper way to convert from `System::Drawing::Bitmap` to RGB `unsigned char*`?

Comment: Use Bitmap.LockBits method.

Comment: Thanks I've looked into it and it's what I was looking for. Do you happen to know what information is in the byte[] I was retrieving?

Comment: You got the bytes for the image in the PNG format.  LockBits() won't get you an image header, it isn't clear whether you need one.  Probably, no other way the native code could tell how large the image is.  Use MemoryStream and Image.Save().

Comment: I don't need the image header. Using LockBits I managed to get the unsigned char*.  I just need the pixel information to render it later. My only problem now is having BGR instead of RGB, I'll look into it and try to come up with an answer here.

Comment: Windows bitmaps have BGR bytes order, it is OK.

Comment: Can I change it to RGB using the LockBits method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be done using the lockBits method, here is a code example:

```
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, m_bitmap.Width, m_bitmap.Height);
    BitmapData bmpData = m_bitmap.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
        m_bitmap.PixelFormat);

    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
    int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * m_bitmap.Height;
    byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);
    m_bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle::Alloc(rgbValues, GCHandleType::Pinned);
    unsigned char * data = (unsigned char*) (void*) handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    //do whatever with data
```

Comment: I recently learned this can be done avoiding the Marshal.Copy, passing the Scan0 parameter as it points to the first element of the Bitmap data. I'll try to come up with an updated answer.